# How can I create a AMP (or JAR) files from my custom models?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I recently re-installed Alfresco, this time with docker-compose to have access to the Governance Services and to prevent some problems I had got with the Alfresco SDK.

However, it seems that I can't find any ways to create AMP / JAR from my custom models.
Previously, I could create them if I edited some files like "share-config-custom.xml" or "boostrap-context.xml".
At the same time, I couldn't find how these files were now located nor how I could add custom models without using the Share Model Manager that seems to be depricated.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you have to use the SDK. The documentation will help you : https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/latest/develop/

Your SDK project (in which you will declare your model) will produce a JAR file. You will put this JAR file into the "platform" module folder of your ACS installation. During the next startup, Alfresco will load your model.

It's absolutely not recommended to put your model directly in Tomcat's directory.

So I think you will have to resolve your SDK problems...

Hope this helps.